# Codeigniter DB query php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have the following codes:

```
$spaces=0;
$str="bike car ";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
  if($str[$i]==" ")
  {
    $spaces+=1;
  }
}
$names=explode(" ",$str);
```

The above code is used to split the words inside the string. How do i do a db query wherein i get the id of the names(words in the string i separated).

Assuming, i have a price table

The table has lets say 2 cols, item name and id

How do i parse DB query wherein i need to get the ids of the item names listed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the id of exploded `$name` simply you can use `$this->db->where_in()`

example :

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

See the documenation here : [Where In Query](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

So the next line of your code maybe seems like this one :

```
$names    = explode(" ",$str);
$this->db->select('id')
         ->where_in('your_table_name',$names);
$query    = $this->db->get();
$result   = $query->result_array();
```

then you can use the `$result` by

```
foreach($result as $r){
   echo 'The id is :'.$r['id'];
}
```

Comment: String:Bike Car
After i exploded it would be this. string[0]-bike string[1]-car

does it assume itself as an array then?

Comment: well you can convert the output of the exploded string to suit the array input of `where_in` commands :D @user3205047

Comment: Say the string is like this.

Bike 1 Car 2

I need to get the id of bike and car. do i have to loop it where array position is even? [0]->bike [1]->1 [2]->car [3]->2
This was the intention of the $space.

Comment: Are you somehow familiar with this error?

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `componentname` IN ('potato')' at line 2

SELECT `id` WHERE `componentname` IN ('potato')

Filename: C:\www\KG1\system\database\DB_driver.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use array_keys and array_values to traverse you array keys and values

```
//sample array
Array
(
    [1334] => Face Towel
    [4552] => White Socks
    [3442] => Lotion
    [6643] => Pants
    [4432] => foobar
    [5532] => bar
)

$items = implode(',',array_values($array)); //will get the array values
$itemid = implode(',',array_map('intval',array_keys($array))); //will get the array keys


$this->db->where_in('items', $items);
// where items IN ('Face Towel','White Socks','Lotion','pants','foobar','bar')
$this->db->where_in('itemid', $itemid);
// where itemid IN (1334,4552,3442,6643,4432,5532)
```

Note that i used array_map to loop through each keys and cast every key as integer.